# HTML lang Tag display language

Tags: php, html, lang

I am asking this purely for educational purposes, while browsing for some reference information for HTML5, I came across the `lang` attribute, while I understand its a way of defining a language, if I were to say make a multi language site, rather than make every page again I would have assumed it would be a way to hide various divs based on the language of the browser i.e.

```
<div lang='en'>Hello</div>
<div lang='ja'>こんいちは</div>
```

So my first thought was if my browser was set to english it should show only the english tag, however upon further reading it seems that the `lang` tag only seems to tell the browser what language it is and added support for TTS, Braile, and other things.

Is this correct, or am I just being oblivious to some other underlying use of it?

If it is just a reader or something similar, would the best way of swapping languages on a single html/php site be:

```
<?php if ($_GET['lang'] == "en") { ?>
    <div>Hello</div>
<?php } else if ($_GET['lang'] == "ja") { ?>
    <div>こんいちは</div>
<?php } else { ?>
    <div>Language not supported</div>
<?php } ?>
```

While I have been a programmer for many years, there are many small things like this that I have simply not come across before.

Regards

Comment: you could use a helper for that so you won't need to do that dirty if else in your php-html. something like `<div><?= translate($message, $_GET['lang']) ?></div>` or better `<div><?= translate($message) ?></div>`, the `$_GET['lang']` will be inside the `translate` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* use CSS to show or hide elements depending on their `lang` attribute. You would just waste a lot of bandwidth.

### Language Tag

The purpose of the language tag is to enable you to mark links, quotes or the like, so you can style them, e.g., add a british flag to a link that points to an English article from your Japanese blog post, and to enable screen readers to provide the correct pronounciation.

### Translations

If you want to provide translated text depending on a parameter, you should do the translation *outside* of your HTML code (just like any other processing). The mix just makes code illegible and a maintenance nightmare.

A common solution is to provide translation data in separate language files, mostly `.ini` files. In your case, they could look like:

`languages/ja.ini`:

```
LANG="ja"
HELLO="こんいちは"
```

`languages/en.ini`:

```
LANG="en"
HELLO="Hello"
```

Now, you can use those in your HTML files.

`index.php`:

```
<?php
$language    = $_GET['lang'] ?: 'en';
$translation = "languages/{$language}.ini";

if (!is_readable($translation)) {
    throw new \RuntimeException("Language file {$translation} not found");
}

$_ = parse_ini_file($translation);
?>

<div lang="<?= $_['LANG']; ?>"><?= $_['HELLO']; ?></div>
```

Both your PHP and HTML code are easier to understand, and the language files are easy to maintain.